# In Android, how do I change autocomplete such that it starts after a single character rather than 2 characters?

Tags: android

I tried auto complete in android, but was facing a peculiar problem with it. Autocomplete shows suggestions only after you type 2 characters and not after a single character. Is that how it is supposed to be ?

How do I change autocomplete such that it starts after a single character rather than 2 characters?

Comment: the answer you marked as best answer is not the best answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

either by setting the threshold in the xml (android:completionThreshold). for example:

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/edit"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:completionThreshold="1"/>
```

or programmatically by calling the setThreshold() method

Comment: I suggest stating that xml method is prefered to improve your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [setThreshold()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can i select the direction in which the drop down opens ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but can you try `setDropDownHeight(0)`

Comment: The direction in which the dropdown opens is determined by the system based on how much space is available on-screen. It prefers opening below the text field.

Comment: this is not the prefered way setting autocomplition treshold. its prefered to edit xml file instead with android:completionTreshold="1"